# Bluetooth adapter connecting and then disconnects the phone

Tags: 14.04, gnome, bluetooth, phone

I have a problem with bluetooth adapter (trust) in ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with GNOME because of I am able to connect the phone but after few seconds it disconnect.
The adapter works on lubuntu 15.04 (very old pc with 2GB-ram and 32-bit).
It seems that the daemon works only if you request a connection: if I send a file it connect, send the file and then disconnect again.
Next I have added to /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf this text:

```
  rfcomm0 {
            bind no;
            device xx:x:x:xx:xx:xx;
            channel 1;
            comment "Serial Port";
            }
```

and then from terminal `sudo rfcomm connect 0`; it connects for few second and then disconnect again receiving this error message: `Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused`
Is it possible to obtain a continuous connection between android-phone an ubuntu-pc?

Any suggestion?